# Reactivate error message in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse, some Java project's `pom.xml` caused an error message to occur. I selected an option similar to "hide error message" or "ignore". Since then, the message disappeared.

As the project doesn't build, I want the error message to reappear again to understand the problem. How do I make ignored messages visible again?

Comment: Preferences -> Java -> Clear.

Comment: @AleksandrM, unfortunately, in my case, this did not bring back the Maven error message in my Maven POM Editor.